# how to filter special characters in Mvc Url Request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, special-characters

sorry , i don't know how to describe my question .

my SEO page is like this: localhost:24099/car/detail/2023/セドリック/グロリア%20ワゴン

```
    routes.MapRoute("Car",
          "car/{id}/{name}",
          new { controller = "car", action = "id", name = UrlParameter.Optional },
          new { id = @"\d+" },
          new string[] { "SphereLight.Controllers" }
          );
```

car/detail/2023 is correct url , however, セドリック/グロリア%20ワゴン is special characters , the page

(car/detail/2023/セドリック/グロリア%20ワゴン) redirects to Custom Error Page .

how can i fix this ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot the action in your route... should probably read:

```
routes.MapRoute("Car",
      "car/detail/{id}/{name}",
      new { controller = "car", action = "detail", id = 0, name = UrlParameter.Optional },
      new { id = @"\d+" },
      new string[] { "SphereLight.Controllers" }
      );
```